# Finding largest and smallest number in python in given input

Tags: python

```
lst = []
while True:
    num = int(input("Please enter a number: "))
    if num == -1:
        break
    lst.append(int(num))
print(max(lst))
print(min(lst))
```

So here is the code. It works but when i enter -1 as a first number it gives an error like "ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence.

How can i exit from the program directly when -1 is entered as first number?

Comment: Just an advice. If you are learning things, then don't use built-in simple methods like `min, max`. Try to implement them youself

Comment: @ZainArshad thank you for the advice. I tried so much at the end i asked here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

once input is -1, you need to see the max and min of the list before exiting the program.

```
lst = []
while True:
    num = int(input("Please enter a number: "))
    if num == -1:
        if lst:
            print(max(lst))
            print(min(lst))
        else:
            print("list is empty")
        exit(0)
    lst.append(num)
print(max(lst))
print(min(lst))
```

Answer (score 0):

`break` only breaks out of the loop, `print()` functions are still being executed. Since `lst` is an empty list, it has no `max()` hence the error.

To exit out of program do this:

```
lst = []
while True:
    num = int(input("Please enter a number: "))
    if num == -1:
        break
    lst.append(int(num))
if lst:
    print(max(lst))
    print(min(lst))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it doesnt display the biggest and smallest number at the end,instead it just exits from the program.

Comment: @Umutcan ok, I have edited my solution to fit those requirements

Comment: Don't forget to `import sys` at the beginning of your code.

Answer (score 0):

if ypu enter -1 as a first number, you break out of the loop before actually adding it to the list. Thus the list is empty, which explains your error.

Answer (score 0):

This code should work for you:

EDIT: Made sure code printed `min()` and `max()` before exiting

```py
lst = []
while True:
    num = int(input("Please enter a number: "))
    if num == -1:
        if len(lst) > 0:
            print(max(lst))
            print(min(lst))
        quit()
    lst.append(int(num))
print(max(lst))
print(min(lst))
```

`quit()`, well, quits the program.

You can also use the `exit()` function too.

[Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#quit)

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can use a `try - catch` code block to detect the error and manage it like this:

```
try:
    ... code that throws error ...
except ValueError:
    ... Handling of the ValueError ...
else:
    ... Normal case with no errors ...
```